# Interop service does not work with NuGet WatiN

Tags: c#, .net, interop, nuget, watin

I'm trying to use **WatiN**; I've installed the latest version through NuGet.
Everything worked great, until I changed the `EmbedInteropTypes` to `false` - for some reason, I get a new error now;
My system cannot locate `Interop.SHDocVw`.

This triggers on the first line of the first test they feature on their site:
`using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com");`

The exact message is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.SHDocVw, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db7cfd3acb5ad44e' or one of its dependencies.

What happened? Why did it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was rather simple - I just had to build the solution and copy the DLL from the folder to the project.